# TinyMCE : icons are not visible

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, tinymce

Image icons are coming if I use html file directly inside of the downloaded TinyMCE pack.If I am using that as web applications all its functionality is working well.But icons are not coming.Am using TinyMCE 4.0.28 version.

**Script for Init :**

```
tinymce.init({
    relative_urls : false,
    remove_script_host : false,
    convert_urls : true,
    selector: "textarea#elm1",
    theme: "modern",
    width: 800,
    height: 500,
    plugins: [
         "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
         "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
         "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor"
   ],
   toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | l      ink image | print preview media fullpage | forecolor backcolor emoticons", 
   style_formats: [
        {title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b'},
        {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
        {title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
        {title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
        {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
        {title: 'Table styles'},
        {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'}
    ]
 });
```

***Updates :***
Other images included.

[image]

**Technology :**

Servlet API Alone I have used for this.No other mechanism.

**HTML by FireBug for Italic Icon:**

```
<button tabindex="-1" type="button" role="presentation">
 <i class="mce-ico mce-i-emoticons"></i>
</button>
```

**web.xml :**

```
<!-- To map all the static contents below code starts -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<!-- To map all the static contents below code ends -->

<!-- To map all the non-static contents below code starts -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ControllerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>tut.core.Controller</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ControllerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<!-- To map all the non-static contents below code ends -->
```

**Problem :**

Why only icons are not coming for Italic as it is not working for emotions and etc?.But other images are coming properly.

Comment: Do you have any security mechanism wrapped around your web application? Something as Apache Shiro or Spring Security?

Comment: The 'icons' look like font symbols for missing characters. You should make sure whatever font tinymce is trying to use for the icons is available.

Comment: @cheffe it doesn't seem to be security problem .Please check my updated Question.Thanks for you reply.

Comment: @Robadob Please let me know where to check the available fonts in tinymce pack.Thanks for you reply.

Comment: The icons are "gif" files. Are you using a war file? Where do you have the image files in your deployment.

Comment: By looking at [icons.less](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/master/js/tinymce/skins/lightgray/Icons.less) file and @Robadob comment, I guess you might have missing fonts problem (look at line 15 and 85).

Comment: Are you sure the CSS file is included ? Please check your network tab in Chrome developer tools(F12). Probably there are seperated CSS files for the icons and the other stuff. The other problem may be that you haven't included the correct image(s).

Comment: Check "/js/tinymce/skin/lightgray/fonts" directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TinyMCE is using icoMoon (http://icomoon.io) for its icons.
Make sure there are `.woff`/`.svg`/`.ttf`-Files in your sikn\fonts folder.
Check that it is served correctly. e.g. with some Browser-Dev-Tool:

[image]

If this is fine, check your `skin.css`. It should contain the styles as a symbol content.

```
.mce-i-italic:before { 
    content:"\e02b"
}
```

Perhaps the file was saved or read with the worng encoding or mime-type.

If you are modifying the icons you need to alter the Icons.less. [see here](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorials:Creating_a_skin)

Comment: "Check that it is served correctly. e.g. with some Browser-Dev-Tool:"

Comment: in web.xml these .woff/.svg/.ttf entries are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try checking dev tools of your browser? Particularly, Network tracing. Do you have nay 404 or 4** status requests?

If you post it here, we can give more information.

*Note: May be you would want to blur/hide your URLs from the trace.*